# Problems with grid

Tags: html, css

I have created a grid. Each item in this grid has a drawer menu coming out of it downwards on hover. What happens on hover is that all items below get pushed down, i want only the item directly underneath to push down.

Url to this site: http://esgu.no/dev/unicef/menupage.htm

My HTML

```
<div class="grid alef">
        <div class="card w33">
            <img src="assets/3.jpg">
            <div class="orange subm">
                <a href="#">Barns rettigheter</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="acti obord">
                <li><a href="#">Historie</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Barnas rettigheter i Norge</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card w33">
            <img src="assets/3.jpg">
            <div class="pink subm">
                <a href="#">Unicef og barn i verden</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="acti pbord">
                <li><a href="#">Dette er unicef</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fakta om barn</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Barnearbeid</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card w33">
            <img src="assets/3.jpg">
            <div class="green subm">
                <a href="#">Unicef-runden</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="acti gbord">
                <li><a href="#">Meld på skolen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bilder fra runden</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card w33">
            <img src="assets/3.jpg">
            <div class="lblue subm">
                <a href="#">FN´s bærekraftsmål</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card w33">
            <img src="assets/3.jpg">
            <div class="red subm"><a href="#">Til deg som er fadder</a></div>
            <ul class="acti rbord">
                <li><a href="#">Faddertips</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Faddertesten</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fadderquiz</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Aktivitetshjul</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fadderrebus</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fadderkryssord</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card w33">
            <img src="assets/3.jpg">
            <div class="yellow subm">
                <a href="#">Kryssord og andre nøtter</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="acti ybord">
                <li><a href="#">Kryssord</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Puslespill</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Rebus</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card w33">
            <img src="assets/3.jpg">
            <div class="dblue subm">
                <a href="#">Du kan</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My grid CSS

```
.grid{width:100%;margin:0 auto;padding:40px 10%;font-size:0;text-align:center}.grid > li{width:auto;height:auto;padding:0}
.grid > *{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;font-size:14px;font-size:1rem;padding:20px}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of, is to create 3 UL's and float them left, with a 33.3% width each.  Each LI would then be 100%, stacking on top of each other.  When you hover over one, it will only push down that UL.

This may not be a valid solution for you but may be an avenue worth exploring!

See this for a quick example - http://codepen.io/conormcafee/pen/MKgdZg

```
<ul>
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Link</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Link<span>Show me</span></li>
  <li>Link</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Link</li>
</ul>

ul {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
}

li span {
    display: none;
    color: red;
}

li:hover span {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this solution. 

I was looking for a solution that breaks up the grid. With javascript or jquery.

Comment: No worries, it's not an ideal solution if it is being used for dynamic content - but if you have full control over it I find it works well